# Where can I find python's built-in classes' methods and attributes?

Tags: python, exception, documentation

I'm trying to find out which methods and attributes come with the mother of all exception classes in python: the Exception class. However, I'm having a bit of trouble since the official documentation doesn't seem to provide it.

The best I could find was this: http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html but that only lists the built-in exceptions.

What's going on? I'm used to the Java and PHP documentations where everything is laid down on the table :(

Comment: Everything *is* laid out on the table with Python. The `BaseException` class is documented on that page, what are you missing?

Comment: If you need the absolute nitty gritty, the C code for the base exception class is: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/exceptions.c I doubt that that will be helpful to you though. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters He's missing the part where it's documented in a consistent, easy-to-navigate, non-conversational manner. With tables of method names, arguments, meanings of return values. And tables of fields, field types, meanings of fields. He's missing the part where the documentation is good. I'm missing that, too. I'm missing it a lot. :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The built-in function `dir` will give a list of names comprising the methods and attributes of an object.

```
>>>print dir(Exception)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribut
e__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduc
e__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', 'args', 'message']
```

You can also get help using the `help` method: `help(Exception)`.

Comment: That is not *documentation* for the Exception class.  Python should have basic method & attribute tables like java.  Right now you have to read a 5-page essay discussing 73 things you don't care about.

Answer (score 6):

There's only one interesting attribute on `BaseException`, and that's `args`. This is documented, so there's no problem.

There are no methods on `BaseException` other than the special (`__`) methods, which you should not call directly. Of these, `__str__` is documented by the sentence

> If `str()` or `unicode()` is called on an instance of this class, the representation of the argument(s) to the instance are returned, or the empty string when there were no arguments.

[There is one more public attribute, `message`, but if you access that you will get a `DeprecationWarning`. Deprecated attributes are not always documented since you shouldn't use them in new code.]

Comment: `__unicode__()` is documented by the `unicode()` method (in Python 2.x). :-)